# i need to set condition for ratingBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello i built a appliction that need to rate photos and do the Average on the rating bar now i want to set that if i am not choos nothing on the rating bar so it will not update to the Photos Data Average like lets say that the raiting bar is on 3/5 start (***)
so if i click on it will not update the number '3'

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            rate = ratingBar.getRating();
            if(ratingBar.?? hes not been clicked ??)
             {

              }
              else{
            upDate();
              }
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(photosRatingInfo.getRate()));
            //Logic
        }
```

Sorry for the poor description ):

Comment: And what if the user wants to rate the photo to 3? Then the user won't tap on the bar, yet you should add the rating.

Comment: yes but if he dont want and he clicked "ok" so its changing the  Average what shuld i do?

Comment: You should start the the rating bar from 0, then you can simply check if the rating is 0, then you don't add it to the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="3.0" />
```

**Here i set the default rating 3.0**

`RatingBar ratingBar;`//Initialize Your RatingBar Here

Use **setOnRatingBarChangeListener** Listener

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                            String answerValue = String
                                    .valueOf((int) (ratingBar.getRating()));
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start the bar from 0 as i suggested in the comment, you can do two things:

derive from RatingBar and override onTouchEvent()

use OnTouchListener, like so:

```
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // TODO perform your averaging action here
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: what do "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP" doing?